# How to properly nest loops and conditions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting content in React like this:

```
const data = [
    {
        header: 'my header1',
        copy: [
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
            'Etiam et risus quam. Proin a mollis dolor.'
        ]
    },
    {
        header: 'another header',
        copy: [
            {
                tag: 'ul',
                content: [
                    'something',
                    'else',
                    'here'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now the goal is to have this kind of markup:

```
<h2>my header1</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Etiam et risus quam. Proin a mollis dolor.</p>
<h2>another header</h2>
<ul>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>else</li>
  <li>here</li>
</ul>
```

Now I'm new to react in terms of how to properly nest these kinds of things especially with handling the different things in the `copy` key in JSX. I've done things like Vue or Svelte before where you can do something like this:

Fully functioning svelte code: 16 lines

```
{#each data as dataRow}
    <h2>{dataRow.header}</h2>
    {#each dataRow.copy as copyRow}
        {#if typeof copyRow === 'string'}
            <p>{copyRow}</p>
        {:else if copyRow.tag === 'ul'}
            <ul>
                {#each copyRow.content as listItem}
                    <li>{listItem}</li>
                {/each}
            </ul>
        {:else}
            <p>OH NO ERROR</p>
        {/if}
    {/each}
{/each}
```

I've managed simply JSX so far:

```
{data.map(row => (
            <h2>{row.header}</h2>
        ))}
```

but when I try to do another `{row.copy.map(copyRow => (<p>stuff here</p>))}` inside of that first map statement like this:

```
{services.map(row => (
            <h2>{row.header}</h2>
            {row.copy.map(rowCopy => (
                <p>hi</p>
            ))}
        ))}
```

I just get a

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

which is hard to debug, considering I didn't have a single comma in the code there.

Just looking for some info on how to do nested pieces like that the proper React way.

Comment: Is the snipped you've posted the whole code? Because there is no nesting in it...

Comment: Do you want to dynamically handle `tag` being something other than `ul` like `li` or `div`?

Comment: @Elias the paragraph below detailed the nested part I wanted to put into the JSX snippet, I put an edit in to post the full thing.

Comment: @programmerRaj yes kinda, each entry in a `copy` key can be a string or an object, if it's a string putting it in  a `<p>` tag will suffice but for the object I will then have to have an if or switch to determine the tag type and then loop through the content keys inside that. hence the nesting issue. basically the issue is  and i can't find good docs on this is how to mix JS and markup to do these little logic checks properly like you would in a svelte, vue, twig template style framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a bunch of components, mainly to keep the code clean (otherwise you land in indentation hell real quick).

I've coded up a solution using TypeScript:

```
type StringCopy = string;
interface ComplicatedCopy {
  tag: keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap,
  content: string[];
}
type Copy = StringCopy | ComplicatedCopy;

interface Post {
  header: string;
  copy: Copy[];
}

interface PostRendererProps {
  data: Post[];
}

function PostRenderer({data}: PostRendererProps): ReactElement {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((post, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={index}>
          <h2>{post.header}</h2>
          {post.copy.map((copy, index) => <CopyRenderer key={index} copy={copy} />)}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

interface CopyRendererProps {
  copy: Copy;
}

function CopyRenderer({copy}: CopyRendererProps): ReactElement {
  if (typeof copy === "string") return <StringCopyRenderer copy={copy} />
  return <ComplicatedCopyRenderer copy={copy} />
}

interface StringCopyRendererProps {
  copy: StringCopy;
}

function StringCopyRenderer({copy}: StringCopyRendererProps): ReactElement {
  return <p>{copy}</p>
}

interface ComplicatedCopyRendererProps {
  copy: ComplicatedCopy;
}

function ComplicatedCopyRenderer({copy}: ComplicatedCopyRendererProps): ReactElement {
  // If you have more than the tag "ul" here would be a good place to create
  // even more components :)
  if (copy.tag === "ul") {
    return (
      <ul>
        {copy.content.map((value, index) => <li key={index}>{value}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }

  throw new Error(`copy of type "${copy.tag}" not implemented`)
}
```

## [Runnable example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mrwafd?file=index.tsx)

## Important to know

### [Read about `<></>` or `React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

### [Read about mapping and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

## Other stuff I noticed

You said you wrote some Vue or swelt. I would generally recommend creating many components. As you can see, well it's all in one textbox... but still, the functions are much cleaner than if you had put a bunch of `if`s and others into the code, adding indents every time.

Technically the `PostRenderer` is a `PostListRenderer`... but I'm sure you can figure that out :).

You see that I added `Renderer` to many (all :D) of the components. That is mainly because the typescript interface for (for example) `Post` is already named "Post", so I couldn't name the function "Post". If you don't use Typescript feel free to just call the component "Post" (way too many posts in this sentence). Or even better follow some sort of naming convention.

I hope you're not confused with the TypeScript, it's just JavaScript with type validation... way easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks @Elias, much appreciated. But holy cow is this an overkill solution to such a simple problem in my opinion. I can achieve the same result in svelte with 16 lines of very readable template syntax and will be going back to that. Personally I find a couple of loop and if/else statements a lot more maintainable and extendable than the react way. Even if you had to add child components inside that structure (as opposed to simple `<p>` or `<li>` tags. Again, very much appreciated the insight into React!

Comment: @Killerpixler You can use ternaries for if-else inside the code. E.g. `{condition ? <span>it's true!</span> : <span>nah fam!</span>}`. As to the overkill solution. You can also accieve this in react with relatively few lines of code, but tust me you will think of me one day when the app gets bigger ;)

Comment: I hope I've supplied you with enough concepts to get your "few lines of code solution " working. If not please leave a comment and I'll update the answer to include the required infromation.

Answer (score 0):

first of all the way you structured that json is not very frontend friendly since the structure of a single key ("copy" here) should always be the same.
it can't be an array of strings and an object later.
if it has to be this way you have to figure out a way to detect it's type then return the proper element.

secondly, in react, each function should always return only one element.
you have to wrap them all in a single div or react.fragment.
plus you have syntax error in that map function. you can omit the "return" keyword when you only return in a single line.

you can map through that json like this:

```
data.map((item,idx)=>{
return (
<div key={idx}>
<h4>{item.header}</h4>
   {item.copy.map((element,index)=>{
   if(typeof element === "string"){
   return <p key={index}>{element}</p>
   }
   else 
   {
   return <ul>
   {element.content.map(listItem)=> <li key={index}>{listItem}</li>}
   </ul>
   }
   })}
</div>
)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, if you create a variable by mapping over your data and convert it to the appropriate JSX above the return statement, and then just return that variable below.

```
const rows = data.map((row)=>{
    <div>
        <h2>{row.header}</h2>
        {typeof row.copy[0] === 'string' && <p>{row.copy[0]}</p>}
        {row.copy[0].tag === 'ul' && 
        <ul>
             row.copy[0].content.map(li => <li>{li}</li>)
        </ul>}
    </div> 
});


return (
    {rows}
);
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't seem to work for the nested map statement. I get an error on the `li` variable  (`li` is not defined)

Comment: Looks like I missed the fact that copy is an array, just modified my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use some composition here, where you would break it down into smaller components that you'll compose to structure and complete the view you are trying to achieve.

Here's just an suggested approach you could use, but may still need improvements.

**Note on my use of memo**, I'm assuming you have huge stuff to render, that may provoke component rerender and stuff.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

```
const HeaderItem = memo(({ headerText }) => {
  return <h2>{headerText ? headerText : 'Oh no! missing header text'}</h2>
});

-------
const ContentParagraphs = memo(({ paragraph }) => {
    return <p>{paragraph ? paragraph : ''}</p>   
});

------
const ContentList = memo(({ listArrayData=[] }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        listArrayData?.map((itemData, index) => {
          // Note on keys:
          /**
           * Per react docs
           * React does not recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. 
           * This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.
           * 
           * The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings
           * 
           * https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
           */
          return <li key={itemData.id}>{itemData}</li>;
        })
      }
    </ul>
  );
});

----
const DataItemDisplay = memo(({ myComplexDataArr = [] }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {
        myComplexDataArr?.map((datum, index) => {
          // going to use Fragment since I don't know if your requirements
          // needs just the header + paragraph | ul
          // focus is mostly on separation of concerns to keep things neat and tidy
          // NOTE: SEE my comment on using indexes as key in ContentList components above
          return (
            <Fragment key={index}> 
              <HeaderItem headerText={datum?.header} />
              {
                datum?.copy?.map((copyItem, index) => {
                  if (copyItem?.tag === 'ul' && copyItem?.content?.length > 0) {
                    return <ContentList key={index} listArrayData={copyItem?.content} />;
                  }
                  return <ContentParagraphs key={index} paragraph={copyItem} />;
                })
              }
            </Fragment>
          );
        })
      }
    </>
  )
});
```